Angular Drag-and-Drop Issue: Child Files Not Moving with Parent Folder
I'm implementing a drag-and-drop feature in an Angular application using PrimeNG to manage a file tree structure. I'm facing an issue where when I drag and drop a folder that contains child files, the children are not moved along with the parent folder. Instead, the children seem to disappear, and the console indicates that there are 0 children even though I'm dragging a folder with 3 child nodes.
Here's the relevant part of my TypeScript code for the drag start event:
onDragStart(event: DragEvent, item: FileItem): void {
  const prepareChildrenForDrag = (children) => children.map(child => ({
      id: child.id,
      label: child.label,
      itemtype: child.itemtype,
      size: child.size, // Include size if available (for files)
      url: child.url,   // Include URL if available (for files)
      children: child.children ? prepareChildrenForDrag(child.children) : [] // Recursively prepare children
  }));

  const dragData = {
      id: item.id,
      label: item.label,
      itemtype: item.itemtype,
      children: item.children ? prepareChildrenForDrag(item.children) : []
  };

  if (event.dataTransfer) {
      try {
          event.dataTransfer.setData('application/json', JSON.stringify(dragData));
          event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Failed to serialize drag data:', error);
      }
  } else {
      console.error('DataTransfer not available');
  }
}


And the drop event handler looks like this:
handleDrop(event: TreeNodeDropEvent) {
    const dragEvent = event.originalEvent as DragEvent;
    dragEvent.preventDefault();
    dragEvent.stopPropagation();
  
    const dataTransfer = dragEvent.dataTransfer;
    if (!dataTransfer) {
      console.error('No dataTransfer object found');
      return;
    }
  
    const draggedNodeJson = dataTransfer.getData('application/json');
    if (!draggedNodeJson) {
      console.error('No JSON data found in dataTransfer');
      return;
    }
    let dragNode = event.dragNode as FileItem;
    let dropNode = event.dropNode as FileItem;
  
    if (dropNode.itemtype === ITEMTYPE.folder) {
      this.fileService.moveFolder(dragNode, dropNode);
      this.filesUpdated.next(this.fileService.getFiles());
    } else {
      this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Move Error', detail: 'You cannot drag and drop a file outside a folder' });
    }
  }

I expected that dragging a folder with children would also move all its children to the new location, but the children are not being included in the move operation. What might be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that all children are moved along with their parent folder?

please share stackblitz with issue replicated
